# Dovecot doesn't start after upgrading Ubuntu, how to raise ARG_MAX?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-22.04, execvp, dovecot

After upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 I'm having a problem with starting dovecot and I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo dovecot -F
doveconf: Fatal: execvp(/usr/sbin/dovecot) failed: Argument list too long
```

How do you raise the `ARG_MAX`  variable?

I have tried finding solutions in `ulimit`, `sysconf` and `exec`.

```
$ sudo getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
$ getconf ARG_MAX
6291456
```

EDIT: Should I add something to the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file?

EDIT2: I have added the following to `/etc/secutiry/limits.conf`:

```
root    soft    nofile      65535
root    hard    nofile      65535
```

and uncommented `LimitNOFILE=65536` in `dovecot.service` but it still throws the same error!

EDIT3:

```
$ sudo doveconf -n

auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = PLAIN
auth_verbose = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_home = /home/vmail/%d/%u
mail_location = maildir:~
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  user = root
}
ssl = required
ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/*.nl/fullchain.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
local_name mail.*.nl {
  protocol imap {
    ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/*.nl/fullchain.pem
    ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
  }
}
local_name mail.*.nl {
  protocol pop3 {
    ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/*.nl/fullchain.pem
    ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
  }
}
```

Exit code: 89

Comment: This is not a question about programming but about how to configure existing software, as such it's off topic on Stack Overflow. You might want look on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for an answer.

Comment: God bless you! I flagged the question and asked it to be moved to Server Fault! Thank you!

Comment: Can someone please move this post to Server Fault?

Comment: They didn't move the question The answer is here. https://serverfault.com/questions/1138566/after-upgrading-ubuntu-dovecot-fails-to-start-with-a-fatal-error-argument-list/1138570#1138570